# Continuity of Cantor-Lebesgue Function: How to conclude?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

**Question:**

Show that the Cantor-Lebesgue function is continuous for $x_0 \in \mathcal{C} - \{0,1\}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ denotes the Cantor set. (The Cantor-Lebesgue function $\varphi$ is an increasing continuous function that maps $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1].$ Furthermore, $\varphi(0)=0$ and $\varphi:= \sup\{\varphi(t) \ | \ t\in G \cap [0,x)\}$ if $x \in \ \mathcal{C} - \{0\}.$ Its derivative exists on the open set $G$, the complement in $[0,1]$ of $\mathcal{C}$, and $\varphi'=0$ on $G$ while $m(G)=1.$)

---

**Proof:**

Since the point $x_0 \in \mathcal{C} - \{0,1\}$, it 'lasts forever' and cannot have been removed in the 'open middle one-third removal' process. So $x_0$ is not a member of the $2^k - 1$ intervals removed in the first $k$ stages of the removal process, whose union we denote by $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}G_k.$ Now let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Then let $\{x_0^{(i)}\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{C} - \{0,1\}$ that converges to $x_0.$  Now choose a natural number $N$ so that $1/2^N < \varepsilon.$ Since
$\{x_0^{(i)}\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$ converges to $x_0$, there exists a natural number $M > N$ such that $|x_0^{(i)}-x_0|<1/3^M$ for all $i > M.$ Then $x_0$ and $x_0^{(i)}$ must lie either in the same interval or in consecutive intervals in $G_k$ for all $k > M,$ since the length of any interval in $\mathcal{C}_k$ is at least $1/3^k.$ Now, regardless of whether $x_0$ and $x_0^{(i)}$ lie either in the same interval or in consecutive intervals in $G_k$ for all $k > M,$ we may choose $a_k,b_k$ such that $a_k<b_k$, where $a_k,b_k$ are in the same interval or in consecutive intervals. The function $\varphi$ was defined to increase by $1/2^k$ across two consecutive intervals in $G_k.$ Therefore 
$$a_k<x_0<b_k \ \mathrm{and} \ \varphi(b_k)-\varphi(a_k)=1/2^k.$$

How do I conclude?